# Phabricator auto backup all diffusion to BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, phabricator

I am using Phabricator to host my git repositories and use BitBucket as my mirror backup. However, whenever I created a new repository in Phabricator, I will need to open an empty repo in BitBucket via web, and then add the mirror link to Phabricator.

Is there a way to automate this so other teammates can easily create new repository in Phabricator and not to worry about backing up?

Answer (score 2):

We pulled our Phabricator repo creation out into a script that uses Conduit to create the repo, then uses an API to create a backup.  We don't use BitBucket for our backup mirror but they should have something to offer.  Also, we do still have to manually add the mirror link into Phabricator.  But, this at least combines 2 of the steps.

The code we use to create the repo is:

```
echo "Creating repository..."
json='{"name":"'"$REPONAME"'","callsign":"'"$CALLSIGN"'","vcs":"git","hosting-enabled":true,"serve-over-ssh":"readwrite","uri":"$URI:'"$REPONAME"'"}'
echo $json
out=$(echo $json | $arc call-conduit repository.create)
```

Comment: It is a good idea to be able to create repositories from command line with this script. It is noted but I won't mark it as the accepted answer as we still need to manually setup the mirror link. Thanks

Comment: Agreed.  I wish I knew a way.  Other than manually updating the database or customizing the Phabricator code, I can't find a way to do it.